# Apriori algorithm on categories data

Tags: python, apriori

I'm working on a project where an input file is provided [categories.txt](https://github.com/englianhu/Coursera-Data-Mining/tree/master/4%20Pattern%20Discovery%20in%20Data%20Mining/data), it is asked to first output all the length-1 frequent categories with min support 0.01. And Then to all frequent category set.

The goal is to write in a file the following data with the absolute support (count), for example :

2851:Fast Food; Restaurants

I retrieve all my data as a list of lists

```
data = []
with open("categories.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    line = line.replace("\n", "")
    line = line.split(";")
    data.append(line)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to deal with the second case, find all combination of all categories with their absolute support (not support in percentage). I haven't found any good Apriori library in python.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is either off-topic (to the extent which it is asking for a library recommendation) or too-broad (to the extent to which it is asking for an implementation of a nontrivial machine learning algorithm). Please edit your question so that it is both on-topic and focused. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Look for a frequent itemsets mining library in python here please: [Mining Frequent Itemsets PY Library](http://www.borgelt.net/pyfim.html)

But I'd recommend you not to use the Apriori algorithm for mining frequent itemsets. Compared to other frequent itemsets mining algorithm it's slow. Check at least the FP-Growth algorithm out which is more efficient and implemented in the linked library.